# Phoenix: is it posible update a presence from a controller?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In Phoenix is possible to broadcast to a topic from a controller with something like

```
MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast! "room:superadmin", "new_msg", %{uid: uid, body: body}
```

is it possible to update a presence from a controller?

#### Edit

My question is because to update the presence you need the socket and in the controller you don't have that.

Now I am trying this, broadcast in the controller

```
MonitorWeb.Endpoint.broadcast! "room:lobby",
    "update_presence", %{body: "hello world"}
```

and intercept in the channel

```
  intercept ["update_presence"]

  def join("room:lobby", _message, socket) do
    ...
  end

  def handle_out("update_presence", payload, socket) do
    ...

    Presence.update(socket, id, %{content: "new content"
    })
  end
```

Comment: Yes, that should be possible from pretty much any module. Are you having problems doing this, and if so, can you elaborate a bit on how you try to do that and what errors you are getting?

Comment: thanks @Frost I tried to add more details.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for not getting back to you in over a month. I simply completely forgot about this.

Anyway, I think the problem here may be that you are indeed intercepting the outgoing broadcast. I don't know exactly what you do in your `handle_out("update_presence", ...)` function, but you need to use `push/3` in order to get the outgoing message out there. Either that, or don't intercept it at all. Only use intercept if you need to modify the outgoing message in some way.